# Finding the chemical formula for an ionic compound made using iridium and nitrite ion

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond

> What is the most likely chemical formula for an ionic compound involving the elements iridium and nitrite?

The charge on the polyatomic ion $\ce{NO2}$ is $-1$, whereas $\ce{Ir}$ is a transitional metal that has more than one oxidation state, and in this case it is $+1$, I believe.

Is $\ce{Ir(NO2)}$ the correct answer?

Comment: No it isn't, and this question doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think it is unlikely that any of such compound would exist.

Comment: Nitrite is not an element, and the question is indeed *weird* at best.

Comment: Iridium forms many oxidation states, +3 and +4 are the most common. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iridium

Comment: There is possibility of a redox reaction between both.

Answer (score 3):

The exact composition of iridium nitrite hasn't been determined because the compound has been poorly studied, although it is predicted to be $\ce{Ir(NO2)3}$ or $\ce{Ir(NO2)4}$ as +3 and +4 are the most common oxidation state. It is prepared by reacting iridium oxide with sodium nitrite at 333 K<sup>(1)</sup> or digesting "chloro compound of iridium" with hot sodium nitrite at pH 1.5<sup>(2)</sup>. The compound is mostly studied in the form of double salts<sup>(3)</sup> and complexes<sup>(4)</sup>.

I did find another compound called *[Hydrogen Iridi-nitrite](http://iridium.atomistry.com/hydrogen_iridi_nitrite.html)* which serves as a starting material for the formation of metal-iridium nitrite double salts:

> Hydrogen Iridi-nitrite, $\ce{H3Ir(NO2)6}$, is stated by Gibbs to crystallise in yellow prisms which are readily soluble in water. The hydrogen may be replaced by metals yielding a series of salts known as iridi-nitrites, of general formula $\ce{M3Ir(NO2)6}$, and analogous to the cobalti- nitrites and rhodi-nitrites already considered.

**References**

1. ELECTRODEPOSITION OF IRIDIUM, G SHEELA, MALATHY PUSHI'AVANAM AND S PUSHPAVANAM,
   Bulletin of Electrochemistry 15 (5-6) **May-June 1999**, pp 208-210 ([PDF](http://cecri.csircentral.net/1129/1/30-1999.pdf))
2. Separation Procedures in Inorganic Analysis: A Practical Handbook, Roland Stansfield Young,Wiley, **1980**
3. - Double nitrite of iridium and rhodium: Inorganic analysis, Analyst, **1901**,26, 107-110, DOI: [10.1039/AN9012600107](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/1901/an/an9012600107/unauth#!divAbstract)
   - Ammonium iridi-nitrite: Journal of Research of the National Bureau of Standards, Volume 10, U.S. Government Printing Office, **1933**
4. The dissolution and recovery of iridium in a nitrate system, G.L.Silver, Journal of the Less Common Metals, Volume 40, Issue 2, **April 1975**, Pages 265-267, DOI: [10.1016/0022-5088(75)90069-7](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0022508875900697)